# What domain functioning level should I choose for Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I recently upgraded my Active Directory 2003 to Server 2008 R2.  Everything is migrated and running great, old Domain Controller has been decommissioned.

I went in to change my domain function level to Server 2008 but I noticed I have two options:  Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2.

Which should I pick?  My domain controller is Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,

EDIT: is there a big difference in functionaly from Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2 active directory?  I have no plans of going back to anything before 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you ever plan on adding any domain controllers that are older then 2008 R2 to your domain?  If not go to the 2008 R2.  If you are going to add an older DC, then you can only change the functionality level to the point of the oldest DC you are going to add.

Comment: I have no plans on going backwards.  Would there be any benefit in doing so?

Comment: No, there would not be any benefit. Microsoft gives you the option just in case. From what you've said, you have no reason not to pick 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

2008 R2 fonctionnal level adds these fonctionnalities over a 2008 fonctionnal level:

- Better and more automated service account management
- Security logs and access lists based on authentication type

I would suggest you to upgrade to 2008 R2 fonctionnal level because these 2 features are nice to have.